# Lorentz Boost Invariance for Two Events

Tags: relativity, lorentz-symmetry

[image]

I am confused on exactly how to approach this problem. I tried using the four vector matrix equations, but I couldn't invert the matrix successfully to solve.

Comment: What four vector matrix equations? That’s one scalar equation.

Comment: The equation means $(t_2-t_1)^2-(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_1)^2=\text{same with primes}$.